# firebase real time database keeps returning null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, bloc

I have been trying this code for a while. trying all I know but it keeps giving errors. please can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?
below is my code for both adding to the real-time database and retrieving data.
sending data to firebase works but retrieving it is my problem.

1. it gives an error of the object 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. I cast it as Map<String, dynamic > since the snapshot object is nullable.
2. since the correct parameter to where the data is on the database why is it returning NULL, isnt it suppose to return the correct data attached to it.
3. after some changes I also get type '_internallinkedhashmap<object?, object?>' is not a subtype of type 'map<string, dynamic>'

```
@override
  Future<Either<DtFailure, Unit>> createStudent({
    required String pictures,
    required String fullname,
    required String matricNumber,
    required String college,
    required String department,
    required String level,
  }) async {
    final ref = _firebaseDatabase.ref(
        'studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level');
    final id = ref.push();
    final studentModel = {
      'userId': "",
      'level': level,
      'picture': pictures,
      'fullname': fullname,
      'matriculation number': matricNumber.toUpperCase(),
      'college': college,
      'department': department,
      'attendance': <String>[]
    };
    try {
      await id.set(studentModel);
      return right(unit);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const DtFailure.insufficientPermission());
      } else {
        return left(const DtFailure.unexpected());
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<Either<DtFailure, KtList<Student>>> viewAttendance(
      String college, String department, String level) async {
    final ref = _firebaseDatabase.ref();
    try {
      final snapshot = await ref
          .child(
              'studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level')
          .get();

      final data = snapshot.value;
      final students = Student.fromJson(data as Map<String, dynamic>);
      return snapshot.exists
          ? right(KtList.of(students))
          : right(const KtList.empty());
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const DtFailure.insufficientPermission());
      } else {
        return left(const DtFailure.unexpected());
      }
    }
  }
```

database image
[image: database structure image]
[image: database structure image 2]

`[log] CheckAttendanceAdminBloc type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast #0      StudentRepository.viewAttendance`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to cast the `snapshot.value` as `Student` in `viewAttendance` function.

Also you are trying to fetch all entries present at `studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level`, where you should try to read a single value at `studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level/studentId`

Comment: I already changed the code. I posted the wrong code before. and what do you mean by reading a single value? I wrote the code according to the documentation I don't know what to add.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing a new student object at path

```
studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level
```

When you read at the same path as above, you will get a list of students not a single object. So the correct way to get a list of students at above path would be

```
final snapshot = await ref
    .child(
    'studentsDetail/${_firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid}/$college/$department/$level')
    .get();

if (snapshot.exists) {
  final data = snapshot.value;
  final students = (data as Map<dynamic, dynamic>)
      .map((key, value) =>
      MapEntry(key, Student.fromJson(value as Map<String, dynamic>)))
      .values
      .toList();
  return Right(KtList.of(students));
} else {
  return Right(const KtList.empty());
}
```

That means you are reading list of students and parsing each student object and then creating a list.
If you are still getting error

> error of the object 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Please share a screenshot of your firebase DB in which we can see that object is pushed correctly or not.

Comment: after debugging by using breakpoints, I think the problem is the fact that it returns Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> but how do I extract the map inside and pass it.

Comment: I know your code is supposed to work but it still gives an error pointing to the data as Map<string, dynamic> as the point of error. I already edited my question and placed the error.